# How do I move large manta flow files safely?

Tags: fluid-simulation, blend-files

I have a blend file that has a really large manta flow fluid bake in it. It's saved in another folder. Currently I don't have the capacity to render it and I want to save it on an external hard drive to free up some space. I want to put all the source files and the blend file into the same folder before I move them. How do I do this without screwing everything up. The last thing I want to do is destroy this sim/.blend before I have a chance to render it.

Comment: I actually found I could just update the folder. I saved a duplicate of both the cache and the blend file. Put them both in one folder and then when blender said it  couldn't find them I just updated the folder. And the data worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest way to do this is to change the file destination of bake files in blender, begin a bake but cancel it and then move the original bake files in place of the old ones

Comment: Cool I'll give this a shot.